# not all data visible with 3 dataset using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I am trying to create a bar chart and based on that i am showing data related to distance, steps and active duration.

I have used chart.js to build a chart , now the issue i am facing is my steps data is not visible somehow when i have all 3 dataset visible. if i just use the steps as a dataset then it shows the steps data but not with all three datasets.

Here is my option for `bar` configuration , probably i am missing out anything.

using the other thread i tried to set the xAxis to offset:false also but it did not work

```
 barOptions : {

        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: false,
            filter: function(item, data) {
              var data = data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].data[item.index];
              return !isNaN(data) && data !== null;
            }
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: false
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{


                ticks: {

                    beginAtZero: true,
                    suggestedMin: 0,


                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{

                type: 'time',

                time: {
                    unit: 'hour',
                    displayFormats: {
                        'millisecond': 'MMM DD',
                        'second': 'MMM DD',
                        'minute': 'HH:mm',
                        'hour': 'hA',
                        'day': 'MMM DD',
                        'week': 'MMM DD',
                        'month': 'MMM DD',
                        'quarter': 'MMM DD',
                        'year': 'MMM DD',
                    },
                },
                offset: false,

            }]
        }
    },
```

and here is the data i am feeding to the chart

```
var gData ='[{"avgActive_duration":0.0,"avgBlood_glucose":null,"avgDiastolic":null,"avgDistance":738.52099609375,"avgResting_heartrate":null,"avgSteps":875.0,"avgSystolic":null,"avgWeight":null,"timestamp":"Apr 1, 2019 12:40:00 PM"}]';
```

here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rxdy97Lh/2/